# Set background-color/image of an element with scrollHeight

Tags: jquery, css, flexbox, overflow

I have a **container div** which has an **innerdiv** which in turn has multiple div elements. The outermost container div has a larger height with overflow for y-axis. I am trying to give background-color to the innerdiv but this style only applies to partial part of the innerdiv, the scrollable height does not get the provided background-color .I tried assigning height() as well as scrollHeight of the innerdiv equal to that of **container div** using jquery,but it doesn't change anything. Is there a way to do it via css/script.

css for the divs used are :

```
 .box {
  align-content: flex-start;
  border: solid 5px gray;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-left: 50px;
  max-width: 900px;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.innerbox {


  background-color:gray;
    background-size: cover;
  margin: 5px;
  flex-direction: row;
  display: flex;
  border: solid 1px gray;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Here is the fiddle link,it appears fine there though but not when saved as a file locally.
https://jsfiddle.net/rawatdeepesh/rtcdL9u9/

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused what you need. If you simply want the grey background color to extend to the border just add the background color to .box in addition to .innerbox. If that's not what you're trying to do please clarify.

Comment: you got it right, that's what i tried to do as well but it didn't work out. I want the innerbox to have gray background ,but the css used only gives gray color to only till the portion of innerbox equal to screen height, it doesn't apply the same to the part of innerbox that exceeds screen height.(on scroll rest of the innerbox doesn't  have the background color provided by the css)

Comment: I worked when I did it. See linked code on codepen: http://codepen.io/Joi/pen/dpGqmm

Comment: If your's looks differently can you include a screenshot.

Comment: I used your css and its still the same, Here is the SS   
http://tinypic.com/r/9u7q4m/9

Comment: That's interesting. Double check that your css is exactly like what you provided in the jsfiddle and there's no code somewhere else affecting it. From what I've seen there isn't anything there to cause any cross browser weirdness and as long as you have no height (including min or max-height) property on the .innerbox it should be fine.

Comment: Also check your html. I spent a whole day once screwing around with my css until I realized I had an extra </div> where it shouldn't be and it what was causing the trouble.